# Use node-imap to retrieve emails

Tags: node.js, imap, node-imap

Here is a module `retrieve_email.js` which connects to my gmail account and download the `UNSEEN` emails after a date. The code is pretty much copied from the example of the `[imap` module][1](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap).

```
const Imap = require('imap');
const inspect = require('util').inspect;
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

const imap = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
  password: 'mypassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});

function openInbox(callback) {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, callback);
};

async function parse_email(body) {
  let parsed = simpleParser(body);
  ...............
};

module.exports = function() {
  imap.once('ready', function() {
    openInbox(function(err, box) {
      if (error) throw err;

      imap.search(['UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'May 20, 2018']], function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        var f = imap.fetch(results, {bodies: ''});
        f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
          console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
          var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
          msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
            if (info.which === 'TEXT')
              console.log(prefix + 'Body [%s] found, %d total bytes', inspect(info.which), info.size);
              var buffer = '', count = 0;
              stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                count += chunk.length;
                buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                parse_email(buffer);
                if (info.which === 'TEXT')
                  console.log(prefix + 'Body [%s] (%d/%d)', inspect(info.which), count, info.size);
              });
              stream.once('end', function() {
                if (info.which !== 'TEXT')
                  console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
                else
                  console.log(prefix + 'Body [%s] Finished', inspect(info.which));
              });
          });
          msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
            console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
          });
          msg.once('end', function() {
            console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
          });
        });

        f.once('error', function(err) {
          console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
        });

        f.once('end', function() {
          console.log('Done fetching all messages');
          imap.end();
        });

      });
    });
  });

  imap.once('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  imap.once('end', function() {
    console.log('Connection ended');
  });

  imap.connect();
};
```

When the module is called in `index.js`, I can see in debug that code is scanned from top to the bottom and the last line of code scanned is `imap.connect()` and then back to the next line in `index.js`, with no connection to the gmail account and no action of retrieving the emails. What is wrong with the code above?

UPDATED: status after `socket.connect()` in debug:
[image]

Comment: I don't know that library but i just made a functions to send emails with Gmail using Nodemailer and i am using Oauth to authenticate, the other option was to allow unsecured connection.  I don't see anywhere you are using Oauth so did you authorised unsecured app connection to Gmail?

Comment: `Simon Cadieux`, there are signin information in `imap` definition. Nodemailer can't be used to retrieve imap emails as far as I understand.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the code, so you need to debug. Is it able to connect at all, or do you have a packet filter that leaves the connection attempt hanging for minutes? And so on. Look for that sort of mishap. tcpdump or wireshark might be handy.

Comment: Could you add the code from `index.js` that uses it?

Comment: `arnt`, `Styx`, I moved all the `imap` code into `index.js` and went through them many times in debug. I could see the value of the `imap` was passed into the imap.connect(). But `openInbox` was never called and executed. There is no error throw out. I don't quite understand how `imap` module works. But it seems to me that the email retrieving (openInbox) was never happened

Comment: In debug, after `imap.once('ready', function () {.....}`, the execution jumps to `imap.once('error') & imap.once('end')`,  and then `imap.connect()`. In `imap.connect(), it called first `Connection.prototype.connect = function() {` and other methods in `connection.js`, and other methods before exit. The whole lot of code within `openInbox(function (err,box )...` was not executed at all. This gave me the impression that the connection to inbox and email retrieving were never happened.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this, this is the Gmail API reference from Google.  On that page there is an example of how to connect to it using Node.js.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

And here is an example from the same docs that show you how to search and retrieve message list using the q parameter:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

P.S. In my comment i was just asking you if you were sure that you did all the other configuration stuff needed to access your Gmail account by code, meaning creating the app, authorizing OAuth or in what seemed to be your case authorizing less secure application access, just have a look at the links you might find that you are missing something.

And do you really need to use IMAP package ???

Comment: Yes, I need to use a solution which is not tied up with a specific webmail provider. That's why I have chose the node imap module. When there is a new webmail provider, what I need to do is to provide new information in the `imap` definition and I can retrieve emails from another webmail provider. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The problem found was with Avast mail shield as middle man intercepting the IMAP traffic and causes the HTTPS fails. Also the IDE debugger stops at somewhere to keep the connecting active but not ready. Here is the [detail of the solution](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/741).